# How can I see the argument names of foreign Java classes in the Eclipse tooltips and autocompletion?

Tags: java, eclipse, parameters, javadoc

Essentially, after compiling utility jars w/ ANT, I'm having the problem that all the parameters are showing up in Eclipse's tool-tip as arg0, arg1 etc.

For example:

```
public void myMethod(String name, String address)
```

After being compiled into a jar file shows up as

```
public void myMethod(String arg0, String arg1)
```

For some methods, which take a significant number of parameters, this can make them quite difficult to use.  How can I keep my parameter names when compiling using ANT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to attach the source files to the binary jar.
Under **Referenced Libraries** right click on the jar file, go to **Properties**, then **Java Source Attachment**.

Comment: Thank you, changing to "project view" and then attaching the java docs solved the problem.  

It does seem a bit cumbersome to do this though, I imagine there's no way to embed the javaDocs within the JAR and have it reference them automatically?